# Redshift where clause not equals returning less results then explicit equals

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, where-clause

For the following query I have tried 3 separate where clause

```
select 
i.po_internal,
o.po_internal,
status,
date(date_trunc('month', date + interval '- 7 hours')) "month",
category,
       quantity_value * price                     "total sales" ,
     case
               when category = 'Countertop'
                   then quantity_value * price
               else 0
           end as                                            "counter sales",
       case
               when category = 'Floor'
                   then quantity_value * price
               else 0
           end as                                            "flooring sales"

from xxx_orders_products i
         left join xxx_orders o on o.po_internal = i.po_internal
```

Option 1 returns 2 results for the test po_internal number

```
where 
(status = 'Processed' or status='Pending')
and 
category = 'Countertop'
```

[image]
Option 2 only returns 1 row with != or <>

```
where 
status != 'Canceled'
and 
category = 'Countertop'
```

[image]
But if I add a filter for the specific PO it goes back to 2 rows

```
where 
status != 'Canceled'
and 
category = 'Countertop'
--and o.po_internal =  'xxx000002764'
```

[image]

How is it possible the where clause with != is filter the row with "Total Sales" = 602 pictured above.

Here is the source Table Data for those who are asking.  I still haven't found a viable explanation.  The top row is orders and the bottom 4 rows are the products.
[image]

Update: 2-25-2021

So some additional oddities to consider.
The following query "A" returns 1 row

```
select * from xxx_orders_products left outer join xxx_orders on xxx_orders_products.po_internal = xxx_orders.po_internal
where  xxx_orders.po_internal = 'xxx000002764' and xxx_orders_products.category = 'Countertop'
```

The following query "B" returns 2

```
select count(*) from xxx_orders_products left outer join xxx_orders on xxx_orders_products.po_internal = xxx_orders.po_internal
where  xxx_orders.po_internal = 'xxx000002764' and xxx_orders_products.category = 'Countertop'
```

The following query "C" returns 2 rows

```
select xxx_orders_products.* from xxx_orders_products left outer join xxx_orders on xxx_orders_products.po_internal = xxx_orders.po_internal
where  xxx_orders.po_internal = 'xxx000002764' and xxx_orders_products.category = 'Countertop'
```

The following query "D" returns 2 rows

```
      select * from xxx_orders, xxx_orders_products
where xxx_orders_products.po_internal = xxx_orders.po_internal(+) and
      xxx_orders_products.po_internal = 'xxx000002764' and
      xxx_orders_products.category = 'Countertop';
```

Per amazons documentation query "A" and "D" are functionally equivalent but return different results.
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/r_WHERE_oracle_outer.html

Comment: I should be obvious to provide table definitions, or at least table-qualify all relevant columns, so we know which table is referenced.  That aside, it's **logically impossible** to get more rows from the same (unchanged?!) tables after adding another filter with `AND`. May be index corruption. Try to re-index.

Comment: Are you sure the rows don't just come up in a different order? The results are clipped so I can't tell.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I'll look into possibility of indexing issues.  I know logically this should be impossible which is why I brought it here.  Fingers crossed reindexing things fixes the issue.  Will keep you posted.

Comment: @shawnt00 Ive gone through all the results and the data isn't there. There is too much data to post here hence the clipped results.

Comment: Perhaps using an `order by` will guarantee it.

Comment: Perhaps the `status` reference is ambiguous? Qualify that and see if that helps. (I have no idea if Red Shift could possibly allow that.)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter the only key we have is the primary key on po_internal.  As a result attempting to reindex results in the following error ```DETAIL:  VACUUM REINDEX can only be run on tables declared with an INTERLEAVED SORTKEY (pid:14678)```

Comment: @shawnt00 redshift does not allow for ambiguous columns. I tried o.status just incase and the results were the same.

Comment: @shawnt00 adding an order by clause did not help either.  While (status = 'Processed' or status='Pending') works I hate leaving something like this unanswered it drives me crazy.

Comment: Perhaps some negative values in the quantity/price columns? The data never lies!

Comment: Take a look at your source tables for the PO in question.  I'm better that there are multiple rows in both tables.  You are getting a cross product of the rows - so 2 rows in each table results in 4 rows out of the join.  Now one version of the PO was likely cancelled and one wasn't so now you are getting all the combos.  You likely are missing a JOIN ON clause to remove these cross products.  Post these rows and we can look at it.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The problem is missing rows not values so negative values are not an issue.

Comment: @BillWeiner The problem is rows missing with "status != 'Canceled'" not extra rows showing up.

Comment: Thanks for the data.  Given what you are showing I'm starting to suspect a uniqueness issue.  Do you define any uniqueness constraints or primary / foreign keys in these tables? If so are YOU ensuring uniqueness because Redshift isn't.

Comment: @BillWeiner the orders are unique based on po_internal. The order items dont have a unique constraint but I don't see why having a guid or some similar data on each row would affect the where clause and not display all rows based on the queries posted.above. "status != 'Canceled'" should be the same as "(status = 'Processed' or status='Pending')" but they aren't returning the same data.

Comment: Exactly - there should be no difference other than how the query compiler is choosing how to execute the query.  Since the results are different there is some difference in execution plans that is causing it.  One way this can happen is if there is a uniqueness constraint (or PK defined) that isn't unique in the data.  This is a common way such things happen.  Any chance of a test case that shows the issue (with dummy data of course)?

Comment: @BillWeiner I have the source data above as well as some additional updates.  I'm reporting this to amazon as a bug and will see what they say.  Their documentation says tings that are functionally equivalent are returning different results.  Will keep everyone posted and thanks for the help.